# Remove weird default starting characters in minted

Tags: minted

### Problem

I am trying to typeset my code using package minted. However, when I chose the default setting (where `showspaces` and `showtabs` options are both `false` by default), some characters (i.e. `^^I`)seem to be **indicating spaces** are shown.

Note the in the following minimal example, the `printf("hello, world");` and `return 0;` are intentionally made to show the aforementioned effects.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in, nohead]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, showtabs=false]{cpp}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
```

[image]

Comment: ^^I is control-i which is tab, the simplest thing is just to use your editor to remove tabs and replace by spaces. (if you try the example as posted above the problem will not appear as this site replaces tabs by spaces in code sections)

Comment: The FAQ section of the minted manual (page 33) says: Tabs are being turned into the character sequence `^^I`. This happens when you use XeLaTeX. You need to use the `-8bit` command-line option so that tabs may be written correctly to temporary files.